# How do I edit the apa.bst file so that it prints the full first name?

Tags: natbib

I'm using the `natbib` package. My bibliography style is the `apa.bst` file.

It currently prints the citation like this:

*Gill, J. (1999). The Insignificance of Null Hypothesis Significance Testing. Political Research Quarterly, 52(3):647–674.*

What I want is this:

*Gill, Jeff. (1999). The Insignificance of Null Hypothesis Significance Testing. Political Research Quarterly, 52(3):647–674.*

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure the bibliography style file is called `natbib.bst`? For sure, there is no file with this name on the CTAN.

Comment: right. I'm using the apa.bst file. sorry about that!

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the `apa.bst` file on your system
2. Save it to `grappa.bst` in your working directory (where your latex file resides)
3. Find the line that says `FUNCTION {format.names}`
4. A few lines down from there between curlies, you see `f.`
5. Change `f.` to `ff`
6. Change `\bibliographystyle{apa}` to `\bibliographystyle{grappa}` in your `LaTeX` file
7. Recompile
8. Done